# Python - Bar plot issue

Tags: python, numpy, powerbi

I am pretty new to Python & I am trying to slice my numpy array data with a third column in Power BI

```
m1=np.ceil((np.array(inp_data["IValue"])))
m2=np.ceil((np.array(inp_data["IValue_conventional"])))
m3=np.array(inp_data["ABC"])

ax.bar(m3, (m1), width = 0.55, edgecolor ='grey')
ax.bar(m3, (m2), width = 0.25, edgecolor ='grey')
ax.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
plt.show()
```

The above code works & generates a plot but I actually require sum of m1 & m2, so when I change above code to

```
ax.bar(m3, np.sum(m1), width = 0.55, edgecolor ='grey')
ax.bar(m3, np.sum(m2), width = 0.25, edgecolor ='grey')
```

the visual gets generated but it is the sum of all elements are being present to all data points in x axis. I would like to have any help that I can get.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The code in the second block appears to be the same as in the first block.

Comment: Yeah, my bad there. Edited it though

Comment: Do you mean you want `m1 + m2`? Because `np.sum(m1)` just results in one value, as does `np.sum(m2)`.

Comment: No, actually m1 & m2 and their sum is of two different methods/calculations & I want the x axis(M3) to show them side by side on same data points